# Only Title page with footmisc package,

Tags: footmisc

Preamble :

```
\documentclass[12pt,thmsa]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[para,multiple,symbol]{footmisc}
\setfnsymbol{wiley}
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

for my title page I have the right footnotes, as i want it.

```
\author{k\footnote{The {\tt C++} .}lolol \thanks{Ce.}}
\title{On }
\date{June 2, 2017}
\maketitle
```

[image]

but after the title page i want normal numbering , 1,2,3.. RIGHT NOW i get symbols *,**

Comment: There is no title page nor something after the title page in the code you provided ;-) In fact, it's an (incomplete) preamble ...

Comment: I think the O.P. wants to have symbols for footnotes on the title page.

Comment: updated question

Comment: Why aren't you using `\thanks`?

Comment: does it make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want ordinary (arabic-numeral) footnote markers everywhere *except* in the title page, I can see no justification for specifying the `symbol` option while loading `footmisc`. Just use the "ordinary" `\thanks` mechanism in the `\title` and `\author` macros.

E.g., something like this in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[para,multiple]{footmisc}
\setfnsymbol{wiley}
```

followed by

```
\author{k\thanks{The \texttt{C++}.} \and lolol\thanks{Ce.}}
```

Comment: ofc this is the solution, my bad I misunderstood the package pdf